# Armature Locked Down in Blender 2.90

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, transforms, pose-mode

I was recently playing around with bone armatures in Blender 2.9, when I moved the bone in pose mode and it deformed the object mesh. But at some point I must have pressed the wrong key or button in the interface, because now I can't do anything in pose mode.

I can select individual bones but I cannot transform them; they won't move, rotate, or scale.

It's like the whole armature is locked down into its rest position, but I have pose position selected. I don't know how to get armature back to a state where I can pose it.

EDIT: I found that I can still transform the bones from the bones properties panel by dragging or manually entering values for X, Y and Z for rotation and scale (not location for some reason), but not in the view-port.

Comment: SOLVED: So apparently my problem was that under Pose Options drop-down I had somehow accidentally turned on Affect Only Locations. Once I unchecked that box everything went back to normal.

Comment: hello, so maybe answer to your own question  ;)